# "No module named" error when importing models from other apps

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to import a model from another app.

I have a folder named "apps" where all my applications live.

so in the models.py of app2, i have the line:

from apps.app1.models import Book

but for some reason, i get the "No module named app1.models" error.

I'm using django1.9 if that matters.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `from ..app1.models import Book` will help you. It's a var of relative path to import.

Comment: You're right Oleksiy.
I guess I wasn't understanding how the paths work for the import.
Thanks.

Comment: Though this solves the problem, it wasn't necessary in Django versions prior to 1.9